# bootstrap mobile menu with custom media query

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a bootstrap menu that i have applied a media query to.
this query should show extra content in mobile view under the expandable "hamburger mobile icon".

**Problem**

it is no longer showing the icon, im not sure if its my error or a bootstrap problem. could someone more verse in bootstrap see if they can see the problem.

**my menu**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse-light-grey navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <?php
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $img = base_url('img/Servare.png');
            $path = 'home';
            ?>
            <div class="logo-img">
                <?php
                echo anchor($path, img($img));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="desktop-content">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <?php
                    if ($this->session->userdata('id')) { ?>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?></li>
                        <?php
                    } else { ?>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('login', 'Login'); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('login/signup', 'Sign up'); ?></li>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-content">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <?php
                    if ($this->session->userdata('id')) { ?>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('members', 'Your Dashboard'); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('profile', 'Account Overview'); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('banks', 'Add Regular Savings'); ?></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Notification Accounts<br>(coming soon)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fixed rate Bonds<br>(coming soon)</a></li>
                        <?php
                    } else { ?>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('login', 'Login'); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('login/signup', 'Sign up'); ?></li>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**My query**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #mobile-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px)  {
    #mobile-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #desktop-content { display: none; }  /* hide iton small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #desktop-content { display: block; }   /* show it elsewhere */
}
```

Comment: remove the `collapsed` class from the toggle button

Comment: Why don't you merge both media queries?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra how do you mean

Comment: @Skelly but did not work

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #mobile-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
    #desktop-content { display: none; }  /* hide iton small screens */
}

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra +1 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-target in the button is set to #navbar (which points at an id). But that id occurs twice on the page (which is not allowed). Now only the mobile page should probably have the dropdown menu using the button, so you can fix it by changing the button:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Then you have to change the id at the mobile content div. Change that to the id the button is pointing at.

```
<div id="navbar-mobile" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

That fixed it for me. Hope this helps!